# How do I look up a cognito user by their sub/UUID?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to look up a user in my Cognito user pool by their sub, which as far as I can tell, is just their UUID. I would like to do this in Java within a Lambda function but cannot find how to do this in AWS's documenation. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of today this is not possible with Cognito User Pools.

Users can only be looked up using their username or aliases. ListUsers API also allows users to be searched by providing search filters on some [standard attributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/how-to-manage-user-accounts.html#manage-user-accounts-searching-user-attributes) but **sub** is not one of them.

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=233751 this seems to suggest otherwise?

Comment: I am afraid, that comment is incorrect. "sub" cannot be passed as a filter key in ListUsers API call. I will make sure that comment is corrected.

Comment: As of today, filter key in ListUsers API accepts "sub" attribute. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html
eg - aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id $POOL_ID --filter "sub=\"$SUB_VALUE\""

Answer (score 56):

Now it works.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html

"sub" in list of supported attributes.
Example for JavaScript:

```
var cog = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

var filter = "sub = \"" + userSub + "\"";
var req = {
    "Filter": filter,
    "UserPoolId": "your pool id" // looks like us-east-9_KDFn1cvys
};

cog.listUsers(req, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        if (data.Users.length === 1){ //as far as we search by sub, should be only one user.
            var user = data.Users[0];
            var attributes = data.Users[0].Attributes;
        } else {
            console.log("Something wrong.");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     // class var
     protected final AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClient identityUserPoolProviderClient;

    // initialize the Cognito Provider client.  This is used to talk to the user pool
    identityUserPoolProviderClient = new AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY)); 
    identityUserPoolProviderClient.setRegion(RegionUtils.getRegion(USER_POOL_REGION)); 


    // ...some init code omitted        

// build the request
AdminGetUserRequest idRequest = new AdminGetUserRequest();
idRequest.withUserPoolId(USER_POOL_ID);
idRequest.withUsername(username);

// call cognito for the result
AdminGetUserResult result = identityUserPoolProviderClient.adminGetUser(idRequest);
// loop through results 

List<UserType> userTypeList = result.getUsers();
// loop through them
for (UserType userType : userTypeList) {
    List<AttributeType> attributeList = userType.getAttributes();
    for (AttributeType attribute : attributeList) {
        String attName = attribute.getName();
        String attValue = attribute.getValue();
        System.out.println(attName + ": " + attValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Old question, but you the `username` parameter is overloaded in Cognito's `adminGetUser` method. It is, unfortunately, not documented: [adminGetUser SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html)

Here's a snippet:

```
const params = {
  UserPoolId: 'someUserPoolId'
  Username: 'random-string-sub-uuid',
};

CognitoService.adminGetUser(params,(err, data) => {
  console.log(data);
})

Returns:
{ Username: 'random-string-sub-uuid',
  UserAttributes:
   [ { Name: 'sub', Value: 'random-string-sub-uuid' },
     { Name: 'custom:attributeName', Value: 'someValue' },
     { Name: 'email_verified', Value: 'false' },
     { Name: 'name', Value: 'nameValue' },
     { Name: 'email', Value: 'user@stackoverflow.com' } ],
  UserCreateDate: 2018-10-12T14:04:04.357Z,
  UserLastModifiedDate: 2018-10-12T14:05:03.843Z,
  Enabled: true,
  UserStatus: 'CONFIRMED' }
```

Comment: Providing the sub as a username for me just says that user doesn't exist, at least using the `aws` CLI

Comment: @redbmk This will work for you if your user pool is set for only email or phone number logins (setting on the Attributes tab). If you chose the other method of allowing multiple login types and/or preferred username, you must pass in `Username` when looking up a user instead of `sub`.

Comment: `AdminGetUser` also does not seem to work if you have configured identity providers for your pool. We were relying on `sub` working since we require username to be an email. This was working because like @hvaughan3 said it works for that pool config. But once we set up an IDP and let users provision it did not work with those users.  Had to switch to `ListUsers` with a filter on `sub`.