# AWS Sagemaker Ground Truth WorkerID for private team

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-sagemaker

I've set up an AWS Sagemaker Ground Truth labeling project and am using a private team for the work. I want to track which member of my team gives each answer.

The only user specific information is a `workerId` as seen, for example, [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-custom-templates-step2-demo2.html).

The sagemaker documentation does not have any information about this ID, nor is it anywhere in the cognito documentation, which I need to use to manage my worker team.

As far as I can tell, the `workerId` is a mturk related id. A `workerId` shows up in the data structures [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_AssignmentDataStructureArticle.html).

My question is how can I map the `workerId` to the specific user in my cognito group? Without the ability to do so, the project will not work.

Answer (score 7):

This is actually possible programmatically, without relying on workers to report their identity - I ran into the same problem, and found the following:

1. Sagemaker Ground Truth does automatic logging of worker actions. Among the things it logs is the `workerId`, with which you're familiar, the `cognito_user_pool_id`, and the `cognito_sub_id` (take a look at the [track worker performance docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/workteam-private-tracking.html)).
2. The `workerId` is Ground Truth specific and opaque, and there isn't a way to get Ground Truth to tell you which Cognito user a `workerId` maps to. However, a Cognito user [is uniquely mapped to by its `sub id`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html).
3. You can leverage the logs' pairing of `workerId` and `cognito_sub_id` to generate mappings, by [using the cognito sub id to query the cognito username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43488445/how-do-i-look-up-a-cognito-user-by-their-sub-uuid).

You can use the mappings above to maintain a database of `workerId - cognito sub id - username` triplets, and use that database whenever you need to figure out what user a `workerId` belongs to. Note, that this will mean the first time you see a `workerId` in a Ground Truth job, you won't have a way to find its mapping. If this is a problem, you can actually solve it by using a throwaway job as suggested previously. The logs of that job will include the mappings you need.

Answer (score 4):

Create a simple custom annotation job in which you ask each annotator to provide their user name/email/full name/whatever. The results of that annotation job will allow you to map workerIds so that you can identify the individuals from your private workforce