# How to lookup cognito user by their uuid with AWS SDK V3

Tags: aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-js-v3

I want to find users by their sub uuid.

In v2 (inspired from [How do I look up a cognito user by their sub/UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43488445/how-do-i-look-up-a-cognito-user-by-their-sub-uuid))

```
require('dotenv').config();
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(require('bluebird'));

module.exports = {
  get: async function (uuid) {
    var cog = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
      region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_ACCESS_ID,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    });
    var filter = "sub = \"" + uuid + "\"";

    var req = {
      "Filter": filter,
      "UserPoolId": process.env.AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID
    };

    try {
      var result = await cog.listUsers(req).promise();

      var name = result.Users[0].Attributes.find(u => u.Name == "name");
      var mail = result.Users[0].Attributes.find(u => u.Name == "email");

      return { 'name': name.Value, 'mail': mail.Value };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it's now working thanks to [aws-sdk-js-codemod](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-js-codemod)

```
require('dotenv').config();
const
  {
    CognitoIdentityProvider: CognitoIdentityServiceProvider
  } = require("@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider");

module.exports = {
  get: async function (uuid) {
    var cog = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
      region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_ACCESS_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      }
    });
    var filter = "sub = \"" + uuid + "\"";

    var req = {
      "Filter": filter,
      "UserPoolId": process.env.AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID
    };

    try {
      var result = await cog.listUsers(req);

      var name = result.Users[0].Attributes.find(u => u.Name == "name");
      var mail = result.Users[0].Attributes.find(u => u.Name == "email");

      return { 'name': name.Value, 'mail': mail.Value };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  },
}
```